# Unit testing failing because of - Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Following is my code in which I am testing `mytestFunc` called on checkbox checked condition.

Checkbox -
`<input id="mycheck" type="checkbox" onClick={this.mytestFunc} />`

**mytestFunc** function -

```
mytestFunc = e => {
    const mockdata = this.state.myList
    const newArr = mockdata.map(x => e.target.checked ? {
      ...x, checked: (<label className="label">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span className="checkbox" />
      </label>)
    } : {
        ...x, checked: (<label className="label">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span className="checkbox" />
      </label>) })
    this.setState({ myList: newArr })
}
```

and I am testing it using jest/enzyme -

```
it('test mytestFunc function', () => {
    const component = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    const customEvent = {
      "target": {
        "checked": true
      }
    }
    const dataList = [
      {
        "id": "DS64XX123",
        "name": "test",
        "gender": "male"
    ]
    component.setState({ myList: dataList });
    component.instance().mytestFunc(customEvent);
    expect(component.state().myList).toBe(true);
  })
```

Error -

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}).
>   If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Let me know what I am doing wrong here and how to correct it.

Comment: can you show how `myList` from the component state is used when rendering?

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to render

```
{
    ...x, checked: (<label className="label">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span className="checkbox" />
  </label>)
}
```

Which should be something more like

```
{
    x.map(y => (
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span className="checkbox" />
        </label>
    )
}
```